# Why Update query not working?

Tags: sql, database

I am working with `SqlServerCe`. The `insert` query is working properly but the `update` query gives an exception.

Here is my code:

```
SqlCeConnection _connection _connection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=MyDatabase#1.sdf;Password=xxxxx;");
_connection.Open();

cmd.Connection = _connection;
cmd.CommandText = " UPDATE [Solve_Student_question] 
                       SET Answ= '" + ans + "' ,
                           Start_time='" + sTime + "',
                           End_time='" + eTime + "' 
                     WHERE Qno='" + Qno + "' AND 
                           User_id='" + userid + "' AND
                           Exame_id='" + examid + "' sectionname='" + sectionname + "'";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

_connection.Close();
```

It gives an error at the line  `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in 
System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Comment: You should use prepared statement to avoid all the mixed variable

Comment: post your exception too

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an `AND` before `sectionname`.  Corrected SQL below:

```
cmd.CommandText = " UPDATE [Solve_Student_question] 
                   SET Answ= '" + ans + "' ,
                       Start_time='" + sTime + "',
                       End_time='" + eTime + "' 
                 WHERE Qno='" + Qno + "' AND 
                       User_id='" + userid + "' AND
                       Exame_id='" + examid + "' AND sectionname='" + sectionname + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.CommandText = " Update [Solve_Student_question] set Answ= '" + ans + "' ,Start_time='" + sTime + "',End_time='" + eTime + "' where Qno='" + Qno + "' AND User_id='" + userid + "' and Exame_id='" + examid + "'and sectionname='" + sectionname + "'";
```